# How to compile extra files into the root directory of an Android ROM

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, android

I'm building a custom Android kernel based on the Cyanogenmod ROM's kernel source code. I'd like to add folders and files into the root folder of the OS (`/`). For instance, after having compiled my kernel, I'd like for an extra folder named `toto` (absolute path = `/toto`) to be created.

I really have no idea which files have to be edited and how to do the work.

---

<sub>Note: If you're an Android user (not a ROM developer) who wants to add files to your `rootfs`, please see [the relevant Android.SE question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130348/can-i-write-to-my-devices-root-filesystem-will-my-changes-persist-across-reboo) instead.</sub>

Comment: Android is a Linux system, but as the question is specific to Android, not to all Unixes. Better place for it is on http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @enedil Generally speaking, Android questions are off-topic here, since Android is not Linux in the common sense of the term (it merely uses a Linux kernel). However, the same question would apply to other embedded Linux systems, so I think it's ok here.

Comment: @Graeme Actually, the root filesystem is compiled into *every* kernel. Usually it's empty and we unpack a cpio archive into it - our initramfs image. You can put whatever you want in it though at compile time.

Comment: @enedil In this case, I believe this question is entirely on-topic. Android differs most from other unixes in `userspace,` but from other Linuxes, the `in-kernel` difference amounts to only a handful of patches. In fact, Android's popularity is a major driving force behind kernel development, and has been for a couple of years. Have a look at the kernel.org changelogs and decide for yourself how relevant many are to mobile systems - Android in particular.

Comment: A similar question on Android.SE: [How to unpack and edit `boot.img` for ROM porting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/69954/107603): answers there explain how to fetch and edit the `boot.img` file, allowing to persistently change device's root directory content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Android, like on many Linux-based systems, the kernel first mounts an [initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) on `/`. The initramfs is stored in RAM; it is loaded from a CPIO archive which is stored together with the kernel itself (or in some other place where the bootloader can find it).

Most desktop Linux systems have a small initramfs which contains just enough programs and configuration files to mount the real root filesystem, which is then mounted on `/`, replacing the initramfs. Android, like some embedded Linux systems, keeps the initramfs mounted forever. Android's initramfs contains only `/init`, `adbd` and a few configuration files.

For Cyanogenmod, you can find build instructions in the [porting guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc%3a_porting_intro). You want to copy more files to the ramdisk (the initramfs image, in Android terminology), so you need to add them to the `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` list in the [`device_*.mk`](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc%3a_porting_intro#device_.5Bcodename.5D.mk) makefile for your device.

Comment: Actually our `initramfs` *image* file is what contains those config files, the `initramfs` *filesystem* is compiled into every kernel.

Comment: @mikeserv I invite you to familiarize yourself with the concept of [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy). Technical writing uses it less than ordinary speech, but it does get the occasional use.

Comment: I will do so, but first I have to check it in the dictionary...

Comment: You make a very good point, and like I said before, the only reason I'm adamant about this is it seems it's so little understood but it's really very straight-forward, so I tend to nitpick on this topic - for which I apologize. I just think it would be easier to show others how simple it can be to engineer your own system from the kernel up if the above detail was made clear. Again, I'm sorry, Gilles, I mean no insult whatsoever.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks you for your advises. I located the file used to copy blobs(blbs.mk). I still do not understand which file(s) has to be edited to add a folder folder at rootfs (/). I can access to the init*.rc files of the rom, but I don't now if editing (by adding a mkdir /titi for instance) these files will allow me to add permanently my folders (/titi). Afterwhat I will add in the file 
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES+= /titi/myfile:<localpath>/myfiles.
Any clue ? 
Thanks again

Comment: @deadeert You put the files you want to add wherever you like, and you add them to `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES`. The `init*` files are not involved.

Comment: @Gilles, If I well understand, if I give an no existing path, in product_copy_files, these last one will be automatically created ? Thanks again

Comment: @deadeert I don't understand your comment. `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` lists files to include in the initrd. You specify both the path of an existing file (where the content will be taken from) and the path where it will be included in the initrd.

Comment: @Gilles. To clarify : From the source code of Cyanogen I want to compile a ROM in which a folder "MYFOLDER" will be at rootfs (with /data /sys /system /storage). In this folder I want to copy some binaries. So after having compile my ROM, I will get a folder at rootfs (/myfolder) holding all my blobs specified with PRODUCT_COPY_FILES. 
I tried to recompile with new PRODUCT_COPY_FILES features, but it did not work.

Comment: @deadeert Maybe you did something wrong, but none of your comments contain enough information to tell exactly what you did. At this point, if you can't figure it out, ask a new question. **Copy-paste** all the relevant information: what device you're building for, exactly what files you edited and what you put there, what commands you ran, the output from these commands.

Comment: I will ask my question with more clarity on a new thread.

Comment: @gilles I post my question here with more details here : 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/how-to-generate-a-new-rootfs-and-add-blobs
I passed the step to copy blobs on file so I marked this question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel docs explain how to pack an image into the kernel itself. From [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt):

> ### What is rootfs?
>
> *`Rootfs`* is a special instance of *`ramfs`* (or *`tmpfs`,* if that's enabled), which is
>   ***always present in 2.6 systems.***  You ***can't unmount `rootfs`*** for approximately the
>   same reason you can't kill the init process; rather than having special code to check for and handle an empty list, it's smaller and simpler for the kernel
>   to just make sure certain lists can't become empty.
>
> Most systems just mount another filesystem over *`rootfs`* and ignore it.  The amount of space an empty instance of ramfs takes up is ***tiny.***
>
> If **CONFIG_TMPFS** is enabled, *`rootfs`* will use *`tmpfs`* instead of *`ramfs`* by default.  To force *`ramfs`,* add *`"rootfstype=ramfs"`* to the kernel command line.
>
> ### What is initramfs?
>
> ***All 2.6 Linux kernels*** contain a gzipped *`"cpio"`* format archive, which is ***extracted into `rootfs` when the kernel boots up.***  After extracting, the kernel checks to see if *`rootfs`* contains a file *`"init"`,* and if so it executes it as ***PID 1.***  If found, this *`init`* process is responsible for bringing the system the rest of the way up, including locating and mounting the real root device *(if any).*  If *`rootfs`* does not contain an *`init`* program after the embedded *`cpio`* archive is extracted into it, the kernel will fall through to the older code to locate and mount a root partition, then exec some variant of *`/sbin/init`* out of that.
>
> All this differs from the old initrd in several ways:
>
> - The old initrd was always a separate file, **while the initramfs archive is linked into the linux kernel image.**  (The directory linux-*/usr is devoted to generating this archive during the build.)
> - The old initrd file was a gzipped filesystem image (in some file format, such as ext2, that needed a driver built into the kernel), while the new initramfs archive is a gzipped cpio archive (like tar only simpler, see cpio(1) and Documentation/early-userspace/buffer-format.txt).  The kernel's cpio extraction code is not only extremely small, it's also __init text and data that can be discarded during the boot process.
> - The program run by the old initrd (which was called /initrd, not /init) did some setup and then returned to the kernel, while the init program from initramfs is not expected to return to the kernel.  (If /init needs to hand off control it can overmount / with a new root device and exec another init  program.  See the switch_root utility, below.)
> - When switching another root device, initrd would pivot_root and then umount the ramdisk.  But **initramfs is rootfs: you can neither pivot_root rootfs, nor unmount it.**  Instead delete everything out of rootfs to free up the space (find -xdev / -exec rm '{}' ';'), overmount rootfs with the new root (cd /newmount; mount --move . /; chroot .), attach stdin/stdout/stderr to the new /dev/console, and exec the new init.
>
> Since this is a remarkably persnickety process (and involves deleting commands before you can run them), the klibc package introduced a helper program (utils/run_init.c) to do all this for you.  Most other packages (such as busybox) have named this command "switch_root".
>
> ### Populating initramfs:
>
> The 2.6 kernel build process **always creates a gzipped cpio format initramfs archive and links it into the resulting kernel binary.**  By default, this archive is empty (consuming 134 bytes on x86).
>
> The config option **CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE** (in *General Setup* in `menuconfig,` and living in `usr/Kconfig`) can be used to specify a source for the
>   `initramfs` archive, which will **automatically be incorporated into the resulting binary.**  This option can point to an **existing* gzipped `cpio`*
>   archive, a *directory* containing files to be archived, or a *text* file specification such as the following example:
>
> ```
>  dir /dev 755 0 0
>  nod /dev/console 644 0 0 c 5 1
>  nod /dev/loop0 644 0 0 b 7 0
>  dir /bin 755 1000 1000
>  slink /bin/sh busybox 777 0 0
>  file /bin/busybox initramfs/busybox 755 0 0
>  dir /proc 755 0 0
>  dir /sys 755 0 0
>  dir /mnt 755 0 0
>  file /init initramfs/init.sh 755 0 0
> ```
>
> Run *"`usr/gen_init_cpio`" (after the kernel build)* to get a usage message documenting the above file format.
>
> One advantage of the configuration file is that `root` access is not required to set permissions or create device nodes in the new archive.
>
> ***(Note** that those two example "file" entries expect to find files named "`init.sh`" and "`busybox`" in a directory called "`initramfs`", under the `linux`-2.6.* directory.  See [Documentation/early-userspace/README](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/early-userspace/README) for more details.)*
>
> The kernel does *not* depend on external `cpio` tools.  If you specify a directory instead of a configuration file, the kernel's build infrastructure
>   creates a configuration file from that directory *(`usr/Makefile` calls `scripts/gen_initramfs_list.sh`),* and proceeds to package up that directory
>   using the config file *(by feeding it to `usr/gen_init_cpio`, which is created
>   from `usr/gen_init_cpio.c`).*  The kernel's build-time `cpio` creation code is entirely self-contained, and the kernel's boot-time extractor is also
>   (obviously) self-contained.