# Change Initramfs script

Tags: raid, mdadm, initramfs

I made RAID 0 by `mdadm'`ing partition located on dmraid [VIA VT6421](http://www.via.com.tw/en/products/peripherals/serial-ata_raid/vt6421/) and Western Digital hdd. Installed Ubuntu on that RAID. Now, when I boot, I get `(initramfs)` ash prompt.

There, I have to write

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md1
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

And hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to resume. Then Ubuntu loads normally.

I'd like to change that behavior to save my time. So, I need to change some script located in `/scripts` directory of initial ramdisk. But everything I know about `initramfs` is that it is gzipped. I looked into `update-initramfs` but didn't find the clue yet. Also, I'm afraid doing something there unless I know what I'm doing.

How do I change my initramfs script?

UPD: Now I know I should

```
gunzip -c initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic | cpio -id
```

Then make my changes and recreate it with

```
find . | cpio -o | gzip -c >/boot/initrd.new.img-3.13.0-24-generic
```

But I still don't know which scripts I should edit.

UPD2: `sudo parted -l`

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: JetFlash Transcend 32GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 32,1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      131kB  32,1GB  32,1GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Model: WD My Passport 074A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA WDC WD1600JS-22M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  160GB  160GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!                           

Model: ATA WDC WD5000AAKS-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags


Error: /dev/mapper/via_ecedbfaihb6: unrecognised disk label               

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/via_ecedbfaihb5: 524MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  524MB  524MB  ext4


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!                           

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/via_ecedbfaihb2: 167GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  167GB  167GB  ntfs


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/via_ecedbfaihb1: 367MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  367MB  367MB  ntfs


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!                           

Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md1: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  6494MB  6493MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 2      6494MB  27,5GB  21,0GB  primary  ext4
 3      27,5GB  320GB   293GB   primary  ext4
```

Transcription:

- `/dev/sda` & `/dev/sdb` each of 500GB is fakeraid named `via_ecedbfaihb`,
- Win8.1 reserved partition on `via_ecedbfaihb1` (390MB),
- Win 8.1 system partition on `via_ecedbfaihb2` (160GB),
- extended partition `via_ecedbfaihb3`,
- linux boot partition `via_ecedbfaihb5` (500MB),
- mdadm 1st partition `via_ecedbfaihb6` (159GB),
- data partition `via_ecedbfaihb7` with the rest of space
- `/dev/sdc1` mdadm second partition (159GB),
- `/dev/md1` made of via_ecedbfaihb6 and sdc1,
- `/dev/md1p1` swap (6GB),
- `/dev/md1p2` extended,
- `/dev/md1p5` root (20GB),
- `/dev/md1p6` home (~300GB)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123491/understanding-a-simple-configuration-file-for-initramfs/123517#123517 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118377/when-does-a-shell-get-executed-during-the-linux-startup-process/118382#118382

Comment: Thanks for the links and quick reply. I'd like to see what scripts should be edited

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122843/52934

Comment: Still no clue...

Comment: You should probably extract the `gz` archive then extract the contained `cpio` image and poke around. Almost definitely your `init` is just `busybox` so you need only create a shell script and make sure it gets executed somehow.

Comment: This is what an Arch Linux initramfs looks like. Ubuntu won't be very different: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123305/52934

Comment: Can you [join me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)?